# Firebase - Imprimir registros por ordem decrescente

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, intel-xdk

Não consigo imprimir os registros por ordem decrescente. Procurei em diversos sites dicas que pudessem me ajudar, porém quando adapto ao meu código, nada funciona!

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Estou criando um jogo no Intel XDK utilizando o Firebase como banco de dados e Javascript para lidar com os mesmos, porém não consigo exibir os registros em **ordem crescente** e nem **decrescente**, que é aquilo que eu quero. Igual a um Ranking.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale= 1.0, maximum-scale= 1.0, user-scalable=no />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.css></script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>NOME</th>
        <th>TEMPO</th>
        <th>ACERTOS</th>
        <th>ERROS</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resultado">

    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var APP = new Firebase("https://testestroop-c52df.firebaseio.com/");
        APP.ref().child('jogada').on('child_added', function(snap){
            var jogada = snap.val();
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td1 = document.createElement('td');
            var td2 = document.createElement('td');
            var td3 = document.createElement('td');
            var td4 = document.createElement('td');

            td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(jogada.nomeJogador));
            tr.appendChild(td1);
            td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(jogada.tempo));
            tr.appendChild(td2);
            td3.appendChild(document.createTextNome(jogada.acertos));
            tr.appendChild(td3);
            td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(jogada.erros));
            tr.appendChild(td4);
            resultado.appendChild(tr);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> E nessa imagem abaixo é a estrutura da base de dados no Firebase:

[image: Essa é a estrutura da base de dados no Firebase]

Agradeço muito a ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que havia "pontas soltas" no código como por exemplo a falta de alguns encerramentos de argumentos `)` no código jQuery e tinhas também um erro de escrita que era na linha `td3.appendChild(document.createTextNome(jogada.acertos));` em vez de estar `createTextNode`.

No `<head>` a biblioteca jQuery também não estava a ser chamada corretamente e faltava o encerramento de umas `"`, ela estava com a extenção `.css` em vez de `.js` :
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.css></script>`

> Aqui tens um exemplo online em funcionamento - https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/tcwpg73j/

E aqui está o código o teu código completo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale= 1.0, maximum-scale= 1.0, user-scalable=no />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <!-- <meta charset="UTF-8"> Utiliza isto em vez da linha acima se estás a construir esta plataforma como um projeto recente -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>NOME</th>
        <th>TEMPO</th>
        <th>ACERTOS</th>
        <th>ERROS</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resultado">

    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var APP = new Firebase("https://testestroop-c52df.firebaseio.com/");
    APP.ref().child('jogada').on('child_added', function(snap){
        var jogada = snap.val();
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        var td3 = document.createElement('td');
        var td4 = document.createElement('td');

        td1.append(document.createTextNode(jogada.nomeJogador));
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        td2.append(document.createTextNode(jogada.tempo));
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        td3.append(document.createTextNode(jogada.acertos));
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        td4.append(document.createTextNode(jogada.erros));
        tr.appendChild(td4);
        resultado.appendChild(tr);
    });
});
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá Chun, o meu computador estava travando muito então eu tive que digitar todo o código pelo celular, vi agora que acabei esquecendo de colocar vírgulas, ponto-e-vítgula, essas coisinhas. Porém o código está funcionando certinho. A minha dúvida é a seguinte: Como fazer para exibir os registros do Firebase por acertos em ordem decrescente. Como um ranking, quem tiver mais acertos aparece no topo da tabela